# React Nested object wont stringify

Tags: reactjs

*Well i try to post the category nested object from expenses to my api(spring boot) but it just shows [object object]  and my api wont take it .I added the stringify, nothing better, i searched a lot already in given answers , i found nothing satisfying for my case.
Easy on me thanks.*

The handlesubmit() post the data to the Api using stringify and handlechange() bind the data from the form. The category object is retrieve from select option tag in the render return(where the form is) .

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

import "./App.css";
import FormGroup from "reactstrap/es/FormGroup";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import {Button, Form, Container, Table} from 'reactstrap'
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import Moment from 'react-moment';


class Expenses extends Component {


    emptyItem = {

        title: '',
        date: new Date(),
        amount: '',
        description: '',
        category: {},
        location: '',



    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            Expenses: [],
            date: new Date(),
            Categories: {},
            item: this.emptyItem,

        };
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleDaysChange = this.handleDaysChange.bind(this);

    }



    async handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const item = this.state.item;


        await fetch(`/Api/Expense`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(item),
        }).then(() => {
            this.props.history.push("/expenses");
            this.componentDidMount();
            window.location.reload();

        })


    }

    //Get Expense
    async componentDidMount() {
        const response = await fetch("/Api/Expense");
        const response2 = await fetch("/Api/category");
        const body = await response.json();
        const body2 = await response2.json();
        this.setState({Expenses: body, Categories: body2, isLoading: false});

    }

    //Delete Expense
    async expdelete(id) {
        await fetch('/Api/Expense/delete/' + id, {
            method: 'DELETE',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'

            }
        }).then(() => {
            let updatedExpenses = [...this.state.Expenses].filter(i => i.id !== id);
            this.setState({Expenses: updatedExpenses});

        });
    }

    async handleChange(e) {
        const target = e.target;
        const value = target.value;
        const name = target.name;
        let item = {...this.state.item};
        item[name] = value;
        this.setState({item});
        console.log(this.state.item);
        const item2=JSON.stringify(item)
        console.log(item2);
    }


    handleDaysChange(date) {

        let item = {...this.state.item};


        item.date = date;
        this.setState({item});

    }

    render() {
        const {Expenses, Categories, isLoading} = this.state;

        if (isLoading) {


            return (<div>Loading...</div>)


        }
        let optionList = Categories.map(category =>
            <option name="category" value={category}  key={category.id}>{category.title} </option>
        );


        return (


            <div><Container>
                <h2>Expenses</h2>
                <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <label for="name">Title</label>
                        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <label for="name">Description</label>
                        <input type="text" name="description" id="description" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <label for="category">Category</label>
                        <select name="category"  onChange={this.handleChange}>{optionList}</select>

                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <label for="expenseDate">Date Of the expense</label>
                        <DatePicker selected={this.state.item.date} onChange={this.handleDaysChange}></DatePicker>
                    </FormGroup>
                    <div className="row">
                        <FormGroup className="col-md-4 mb-3">
                            <label for="location">Location</label>
                            <input type="text" name="location" id="location" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                        </FormGroup></div>
                    <div className="row">
                        <FormGroup className="col-md-4 mb-3">
                            <label htmlFor="amount">Amount</label>
                            <input type="number" name="amount" id="amount" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                        </FormGroup></div>
                    <div>
                        <FormGroup>
                            <Button color="primary" type="submit">save</Button>
                            <br/>
                            <Button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" tag={Link} to="/">Cancel</Button>

                        </FormGroup></div>
                </Form>

            </Container>
                <Container>
                    <h3>Expense List</h3>
                    <Table className="mt-4">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="auto">Category</th>
                            <th width="auto">Name</th>
                            <th width="auto">Description</th>
                            <th width="auto">Amount</th>
                            <th width="auto">Date</th>
                            <th width="auto">location</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        {Expenses.map(expense =>
                            <tr>
                                <td key={expense.category.id}>{expense.category.title}</td>
                                <td>{expense.title}</td>
                                <td>{expense.description}</td>
                                <td>{expense.amount} €</td>
                                <td><Moment date={expense.date} format="YYYY/MM/DD"/></td>
                                <td>{expense.location}</td>
                                <td><Button size="sm" color="danger"
                                            onClick={() => this.expdelete(expense.id)}>Delete</Button></td>

                            </tr>)}
                        </tbody>
                    </Table>

                </Container>

            </div>);

    }


}

export default Expenses;
```

Comment: Hi, interesting, is there an error message?

Comment: only from my Api that it cant accept the [object object] , on the react aspect, react just accept the category as [object object] in the console.log ,nothing detailed as it should be for my api. Isn'it possible that json stringify the item object in general and not my nested object?

Comment: Can you provide the error message from the server? You don't JSON stringify `this.state.item` where you log it in `handleChange`, which would also only log the current state, not the enqueued state update. Also, why do you define component state twice, and why are you invoking react component lifecycle methods manually?

Comment: Drew Reese, what do you mean by "invoking the component lifecycle methods manually"?

Comment: it goes outside the category.{"title":"mega youpie","date":"2020-10-05T20:05:21.232Z","amount":"","description":"mega youpie","location":"","category":{},"":"[object Object]"}

Comment: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `slash.code.pokiApp.domain.Category` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('[object Object]'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException:

Comment: You invoke `this.componentDidMount();` in `handleSubmit`. Your `this.state.item` appears to also have an undefined, or rather `""` key with an object value. My guess it is the select input for category missing a name attribute for updating state in `handleChange`.

Comment: thanks , i updated the select tag with a name attribute referefing to the category, i console.log a json stringify of the item after handlechange just before the posting , and it keep showing [object object ] in the category section of the object, my api wont accept it at all now, i dont know what to do.I was wondering , is uuid object need a special care? I edited the new version of the code